Hyper-V VM does not use all the EPYC 7543P CPU power
I have a DELL server with an AMD EPYC 7543P 32-Core Processor.
I run Hyper-V as VM Hypervisor on a Windows 2022 server OS.
All is working right on the Host but the VM are not able to use all the power of each V-CPU Core... The frequency is as locked at 50% (1.4 GHz vs 2.80 GHz).
I found a solution to improve this changing the VM mode with the following command
bcdedit /set hypervisorschedulertype Classic

After the reboot it is better but the CPU max frequency is locked at 2.3 GHz.
I make some power test using 7zip and I find the same differencies (same CPU core numbers) :

Without the modification ~45000 GIPS
With the modification ~69000 GIPS
Directly on the Host ~90000 GIPS

And to finish, I am able to get the full power starting the CPU-Z application (only starting it).
